# How to run Fifa 10 on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, wine, games, disk

I have an original Fifa 10 Disk. How should I install it on Ubuntu? I don't want to use Wine. Is there an alternative?

Comment: As it's probably a game which runs only on Windows, you can either use Wine, a Windows virtual machine, dual-boot or look if there is a Linux compatible version (e.g. through Steam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux cannot run Win32 apps natively.

You have four options:

- Try it in WINE
- Try it in PlayOnLinux
- Run it in a VM.
- Dual boot with Windows (Cost of $115)

---

**I recommend the WINE method. According to the official DB, it gets** [a very good compatibility rating](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17996&iTestingId=45634).